# TCP Port 67 and 68 for DHCP

Tags: tcp, port, dhcp

Why are TCP and UDP ports 67 and 68 reserved for DHCP? Where does DHCP use TCP? I saw the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers and am not able to understand why TCP port is reserved when DHCP works on UDP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard port numbers are officially assigned by IANA, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, and it is their long standing policy when assigning new numbers to TCP or UDP-based services to reserve the same port number for both the TCP and UDP protocols, even when the service in question "always" uses only one of the protocols.

As you can see in the current IANA [numbers list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), tons of effectively TCP-only services (FTP, Telnet, SSH, SMTP, HTTP, etc.) are also assigned the same port number for UDP.